# TLS Private Key Secured with Hardware Fingerprint

Tags: tls, proxy, fingerprinting, os-fingerprinting

I worked for a company where our TLS Private Key was accidentally leaked to the Internet and it was a big mess. The strategy the security team came up for avoiding this in the future was "be more careful who you trust with access to the Private Key."

I was wondering if there's a better option - like maybe a [hardware fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) for private keys e.g. the kind that are used in DRM like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/hardware-drm). I'm pretty sure TLS doesn't support this but what if there was a CA that instead of issuing just TLS certs they issued binaries of a [TLS termination proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_termination_proxy) and embedded in the binary was the private key AND the binary was restricted to run on certain hardware fingerprints e.g. some specific servers in a certain companies data center.

Wouldn't that make it impossible or at least more difficult to "leak" the private key? And even if the TLS proxy binary got leaked it presumably couldn't be run because of the hardware fingerprint. I know the binary could still be [revered engineered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/926172/3501751) and maybe that defeats the purpose of this whole approach but I was curious if anything like this has been explored.

My question is it possible for a company to have a private key that no one in that company has direct access to so you aren't required to trust someone to not leak the leak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are well established solutions for the problem of protecting the private key - use a [hardware security module (HSM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module). Here the private key never leaves the hardware because any operations are done in the hardware. The key is often also created on the hardware, so there is not even the opportunity to grab it before it gets stored on the HSM. And usually the hardware is protected against physical tampering too, i.e. the key gets destroyed if tampering gets detected so that it does not leak.

Depending on the necessary performance for key operations HSM come in various form factors, from slow smartcards or USB sticks to large applicances. For weaker security requirements there also exist software-only implementations. These "Soft HSM" can be run as a separate process on the same machine (running as a different user, so standard user cannot access the private key) or maybe as a process on an external machine for more protection.

And there are [standards for accessing such a HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_11), so it can be integrated with existing software stacks which need private key operations, like in TLS libraries, PGP or S/MIME, code and document signing etc.